# Can you bring an e-scooter on-board MTRX trains?

Tags: trains, luggage, sweden, scooters, mtrx

I've looked through [the page about luggage](https://mtrx.travel/en/kundservice/bagage) at their website but there's no mentioning of e-scooters. Does anyone know if they're allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, you can't bring an electric scooter on-board MTRX trains in Sweden.

From the [general travel conditions](https://mtrx.travel/en/allmanna-resevillkor):

> 10.4 Bicycles (including electric bicycles), electric scooters, electric mopeds and similar vehicles cannot be brought on-board.

However, they're currently allowed on other some other Swedish trains travelling the same routes.